# Using different Jquery versions without conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

So, let's start with situation. I have a website which uses `Jquery 1.4.2` as the main version of Jquery.
But user's are able to use custom templates which are using other versions(1.2.1,1.5.1,etc.). So it bring with it conflicts in some situations.
For example, here

```
//included in my main view
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
              alert($().jquery);
          });
</script>

//included in custom template
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          alert($().jquery);
        });
</script>
```

So both of them are alerting **1.5.1**(because of initializing when document is ready). So I want to prevent this situations.

Now I've get only one solution in my head - use `noConflict(true)` and change all `$` and `Jquery` symbols to new symbol in **all** plugins used in my site.
Is there more elegant solution or I really need to rename all plugin's used in my site?

*P.S.* Another way maybe will be using backwards compatibility plugins, but in this situation I will need to include a lot of plugins to make it compatible with all versions.

Comment: If the plugins are structured properly, they will use the `jQuery` object which is defined at that moment. So you just have to load them in the proper order. For using the correct version in your own code, the `ready` callbacks get passed a reference to jQuery as first argument.

Comment: In my example, first alert is getting 1.5.1 instead of 1.4.2 and this situation can appear in lots of plugins, I suppose.

Comment: But plugins are normally defined as `(function($) {...}(jQuery))`, i.e. inside the plugin `$` refers to whatever `jQuery` refers to at that moment. In your case, otoh, you are accessing the **global** `$`, which is overwritten later by the second jQuery script. The equivalent in your case  would be `$(function($) {...})`. Give it a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
**//included in my main view**
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
              alert($().jquery);
          });
</script>

**//included in custom template**
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $151 = jQuery.noConflict();
        $151(function ($) { // In this scope $ === $151, or jQuery 1.5.1
          alert($().jquery);
          // $ !== jQuery.
          // $().jquery = 1.5.1
          // jQuery().jquery = 1.4.2
        });
        // outside the scope
        // $ === jQuery
        // $().jquery returns 1.4.2
</script>
```

---

How to use jQuery.noConflict();

`$.noConflict()` returns a copy of jQuery, you can capture it a variable like so:

`var j = $.noConflict()`

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
// jQuery === $
//$().jquery === 1.5.1
```

.

```
jQ151 = $.noConflict();
```

.

```
// jQ151 !== $
// jQ151().jquery === 1.5.1
// $().jquery === 1.4.2
```

---

in `jQuery.ready(function() {..` or simply `jQuery(function() {..` the first argument is a local copy of jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        // in this scope $ refers to jQuery version 1.4.2
    });
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        // in this scope $ refers to jQuery version 1.5.1
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Voted up. If there is an error, please state it after voting down! :)

Comment: In the question I have already wrote about noConflict and renaming $'s and jQuery's. The question is about finding more elegant way.

Comment: @ChuckNorris see edit. But i think I already mention this in the first answer.

Comment: I didn't see $ symbol as parameter of function first time. I will test it, thanks.